# How to run qtconsole connected to ipython3 instance?

Tags: ipython, python-3.4, qtconsole

When I run `%qtconsole` from within *ipython3* I get `ERROR: Line magic function`%qtconsole`not found.`, but `ipython3 qtconsole` in terminal starts fine. According to this, how can I run *qtconsole* instance connected to *ipython3* instance? And how to run it on a single core -- `rc[0].execute(%qtconsole)`?

P.S. If someone know, tell me please how to escape `(backquote) symbol in code-mode.

Comment: If you just run `ipython3` in a terminal, what you get is a pure terminal interface, it's not running a kernel that the Qt console can talk to. If you run `ipython3 console`, you'll get a similar interface but it will be talking to a kernel, so you can start a Qt console to interact with it.

Comment: Thank You, good guy. It really solved my problem. Make your comment an answer, so I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

If you just run `ipython3` in a terminal, what you get is a pure terminal interface, it's not running a kernel that the Qt console can talk to.

If you run `ipython3 console`, you'll get a similar interface but it will be talking to a kernel, so you can start a Qt console to interact with it. You can either run `%qtconsole` from inside that interface, or run `ipython qtconsole --existing` in a shell to start a Qt console and connect to an existing kernel.